# Radius of convergence of ${\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}} \frac{z^{2n}}{4^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to calculate the Radius of convergence of $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}} \frac{z^{2n}}{4^n}$

Can we use the Root test? How?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in the usual sense by setting $w=z^{2}$

Comment: Great, thats what i was thinking as well. What about $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}} \frac{z^{n}}{1+2^n}$? Can it be done by Root test as well?

Comment: I would rather prefer estimating the term in the following way $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{|z|}{2})^{n}}=\frac{|z|^{n}}{2^{n}+2^{n}}\leq \frac{|z|^{n}}{1+2^{n}} \leq \frac{|z|^{n}}{2^{n}}=(\frac{|z|}{2})^{n}$ . Then it is a straightforward comparison with the standard geometric serie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{4^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac z2\right)^{2n}$$
It's just a geometric series! You should it converges for when $\left|\dfrac z2\right|^2<1\Longleftrightarrow |z|<2$ and diverges for $|z|>2$.

---

As for $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{1+2^n}$, use the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{2^n}$ which is just a geometric series with radius of convergence $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Root test is most appropriate:

Here you have the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$, where
$$
a_k=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll} 
0 & \text{if $k$ odd}, \\
2^{-k} & \text{if $k$ even}.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then
$$
\lvert a_k\rvert^{1/k}=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll} 
0 & \text{if $k$ odd}, \\
1/2 & \text{if $k$ even}.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Hence
$$
L=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\lvert a_k\rvert^{1/k}=\frac{1}{2},
$$
and thus the radius of convergence of the power series $R=1/L$ is equal to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use the root test, but you don't really need it.  If $|z| \ge 1$, then the term does not go to zero, and if $|z|<1$ it is a convergent geometric series.